# Standardize Color Emoji using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, emoji

I am standardizing the color of the emojis, at the moment this code calculates the emojis with greater presence but it does not join the emojis that are of the same type.

```
import emoji
import pandas as pd

# Crear un DataFrame de ejemplo
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3],
        'renderedContent': ['Hello ', 'How are you? ', '']}
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data)


text = df5['renderedContent'].str.cat(sep='\n')
out = (pd.DataFrame(emoji.emoji_list(text)).value_counts('emoji')
         .rename_axis('Smiley').rename('Count').reset_index()
         .assign(Type=lambda x: x['Smiley'].apply(emoji.demojize)))
most_used = out.head(10)
most_used
```

This is the output:

[image]

The thumbs up emoji should be 3 instead of 1. And the smile 2 instead of 1.

How can I unify them? I am using the latest version of the emoji library but I have not been able to standardize it.

Comment: That's up to you.  You'll have to create a mapping.  There is no central database that maps "subtypes of emojis".

Answer (score 1):

As @Tim mentioned you need to create the mapping by yourself :

```
import emoji
import pandas as pd
import re

data = {'id': [1, 2, 3],
        'renderedContent': ['Hello ', 'How are you? ', '']}
df5 = pd.DataFrame(data)

def standardize_emoji(text):
    # Remove skin tone variations
    text = re.sub(r'', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'', '', text)
    text = re.sub(r'', '', text)
    # Add more standardization here if needed
    return text

# Apply standardization to the text
text = df5['renderedContent'].str.cat(sep='\n')
text = standardize_emoji(text)

out = (pd.DataFrame(emoji.emoji_list(text)).value_counts('emoji')
        .rename_axis('Smiley').rename('Count').reset_index()
        .assign(Type=lambda x: x['Smiley'].apply(emoji.demojize)))
most_used = out.head(10)
most_used
```

Comment: I'd be inclined to replace all the substitutions in `standardize_emoji` with a single substitution `text = re.sub(r'[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]', '', text)` to remove skin tones> If you want something broader targeting all emoji modifiers, I'd look at using the `regex` module instead of `re`, and use the pattern `r'\p{Emoji_Modifier}'`.

Answer (score 0):

From [Emojipedia](https://emojipedia.org/emoji-modifier-sequence#list)

> An Emoji Modifier Sequence is created automatically when a modifier character is inserted after a supported base emoji character, resulting in a single emoji with skin tone.
> Many emojis with skin tones are Emoji ZWJ Sequences, due to the presence of additional characters for gender, multiple people, or a combination of people and objects.

So, you can remove "skin tones" suffix to unify it:

```
skin_tones = '[\U0001F3FB-\U0001F3FF]'
df5['renderedContent'] = df5['renderedContent'].str.replace(skin_tones, '', regex=True)
```

Output after your code:

```
>>> most_used
  Smiley  Count                           Type
0            3                    :thumbs_up:
1            1                :grinning_face:
2            1  :grinning_face_with_big_eyes:
```